# trying to change the format of dates R

Tags: r, dataframe, date

I have a df as follows:

```
x = data.frame(
  week = c("2020-08-09", "2017-11-11", "2017-06-18", "2020-09-07", "2020-09-07", "2020-09-07",
           "2020-09-12", "2020-08-23", "2019-12-22", "2017-10-29"),
  store = c(14071, 11468, 2428, 17777, 14821, 10935,  5127, 14772, 14772, 14772)
)
```

I am trying to remove the "-" in the week values and add "01" to the end of them so that "2020-08-09" would be "2020080901" and so on. Is there an easy way to do this using regex/some other method for the week column? Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

We may convert to `Date`,  and remove the `-` with `str_remove_all` or use `format` and add the 01 at the end

```
library(lubridate)
library(dplyr)
x <- x %>%
     mutate(week = format(ymd(week), "%Y%m%d01"))
```

-output

```
x
         week store
1  2020080901 14071
2  2017111101 11468
3  2017061801  2428
4  2020090701 17777
5  2020090701 14821
6  2020090701 10935
7  2020091201  5127
8  2020082301 14772
9  2019122201 14772
10 2017102901 14772
```

---

Or using `base R`

```
x$week <- format(as.Date(x$week), "%Y%m%d01")
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is an alternative way:

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)
x %>% 
  mutate(week = paste0(str_remove_all(week, "-"), "01"))
```

```
         week store
1  2020080901 14071
2  2017111101 11468
3  2017061801  2428
4  2020090701 17777
5  2020090701 14821
6  2020090701 10935
7  2020091201  5127
8  2020082301 14772
9  2019122201 14772
10 2017102901 14772
```

Answer (score 0):

A regex approach using `sub` -

```
sub('(\\d+)-(\\d+)-(\\d+)', '\\1\\2\\301', x$week)
# [1] "2020080901" "2017111101" "2017061801" "2020090701" "2020090701" "2020090701"
# [7] "2020091201" "2020082301" "2019122201" "2017102901"
```